# Merging Two Laravel Collections keeping the original keys

Tags: laravel-5

I have the following two collections:

```
Collection {#402 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    4007 => "4007 - Container Deposit - 18.00 Drum - In Stock: 0.00"
  ]
}

Collection {#398 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    1000 => "1000 - Acetone - 162.00 KG - In Stock: 10000.00"
    1001 => "1001 - Acetone - 15.80 KG - In Stock: 0.00"
    24662 => "24662 - 1L Untd Antifreeze Orange FO2272A60(Prem - 1.00 Litre - In Stock: 0.00"
  ]
}
```

Using Laravel's collection merge function:

```
$merged = $ref_prod_containers->merge($ref_cust_prod);
dd($merged);
```

I get the following:

```
Collection {#397 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => "4007 - Container Deposit - 18.00 Drum - In Stock: 0.00"
    1 => "1000 - Acetone - 162.00 KG - In Stock: 10000.00"
    2 => "1001 - Acetone - 15.80 KG - In Stock: 0.00"
    3 => "24662 - 1L Untd Antifreeze Orange FO2272A60(Prem - 1.00 Litre - In Stock: 0.00"
  ]
}
```

However I wish to retain the original keys. The merge function is removing them and replacing with 0,1,2,3.

Thanks, Julian

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use Laravel Collection's `union()` method. Beware that this behaves differently from `merge()` when dealing with duplicate keys: if the same key is present in both `$array1` and `$array2` and you go `$merged = $array1->union($array2)`, then the value of `$array1` will end up in the `$merged` collection, and the value of `$array2` will be discarded ([Laravel union documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-union)).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. My key is a primary key so I don't need to worry about duplicate keys.

Comment: This also mirrors the behavior of php's array union operator (+).

Comment: Is there a method in Laravel collections to define a callback and decide what to do in case of duplicated keys?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use string keys for the merging and merged collection. 
From the laravel docs section **collections**, function merge()

```
If the given array's keys are numeric, the values will be appended to the end of the collection:
```

Comment: I just tried this idea, thinking too that it would work, but it does not: `collect(['100' => 'aa', '200' => 'bb'])->merge(['100' => 'AA', '200' => 'BB'])` yields `['aa', 'bb', 'AA', 'BB']`

Comment: @cjauvin If you try `collect(['a100' => 'aa', 'b200' => 'bb'])->merge(['a100' => 'AA', 'b200' => 'BB'])` yelds `[ "a100" => "AA", "b200" => "BB"]`. It works by prepending a char and forcing the key to be seen as string.

Comment: Absolutely, but I found out later that `union` works better for my needs..